# Grep through subdirectories

Tags: command-line, bash, grep

[Add a string to a text file from terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11031/add-a-string-to-a-text-file-from-terminal)

I've been looking at this thread. The solution (number 2, with `ls grep`) works perfectly for files called .txt in the current directory. How about if I wanted to search through a directory and the subdirectories?

For example, I have to search through a directory that has many subdirectories, and they have many subdirectories etc.

I'm new to Linux sorry, so I'm not sure if this is the right place

Comment: check this http://askubuntu.com/questions/55325/how-to-use-grep-command-to-find-text-including-subdirectories

Answer (score 7):

Use the -R (equivalent to `--recursive`) option to grep.

EDIT: after reading the thread, in the combination `ls /mydata | grep txt$` you do not need recursive grep, but *recursive ls*. You do not grep the files; you grep the output of ls, which happens to be a list of files.

"Recursive ls" is called find :-)

```
find /mydata -type f | grep txt$
```

or, better,

```
find /mydata -type f -name '*.txt'
```

Comment: You should add -type f so that only files will be displayed... in your example folder with name "bla.txt" will be listed too. But in real life you don't have folder with names like that :P

Comment: Naturally. But I never do that.

Answer (score 4):

I actually solved it by using `find . type -f` instead of `ls`

Comment: Exactly; but that *precisely* is solution #1.