# How can I modify a line which contains 2nd occurence of a string?

Tags: command-line

[This](https://askubuntu.com/q/11031/743263) post explains how to add a line at the beginning of a file from the terminal. But how do I modify from the terminal a line somewhere in a file if I do not know which line it is?

I should modify the line `eni=10.*10**9` to `eni=10.*10**8` note the exponents. It is the second time that `eni` appears

Comment: Do you mean the exact middle of a file?

Comment: No I mean somewhere in the file

Comment: If not line number is there any pattern or some kind of phrase which is to be followed? Like add this line before a line which contains "blabla".

Comment: @Kulfy it is the second time the term 'eni' appears if that can be useful

Comment: What exactly kind of modifications do you want? Please [edit] your question and try to make it more descriptive and specific.

Comment: @Kulfy I added the required explanations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
line=$(grep -n -m2 "eni" file | tail -n1 | cut -f1 -d:)

sed -i $line's/9$/8/' file
```

Comment: @wjandrea modified the answer, take a look.

Comment: Nice! You could simplify getting the line number: `line="$(awk '/eni/ {count+=1;if(count==2){print NR}}' test.txt)"`

Comment: This answer will match the second occurrence of `eni` and return the line number. Then it will change the last occurrence of `9` with `8` in that line. If more than one `9` are present in the same line, it will only change the last one and might miss the intended one.

Comment: @Raffa Yes, a more elaborate regex could be done, but OP's data doesn't show more text after the line, that's why I chose to simplify it to match what OP *shows* as a line. Note that OP wrote "I should modify the line", not *x content* in the line.

Comment: @guillermochamorro You did a good job, but I however recommend you add such explanation to your answer as it could prevent unintended modification to the file. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Since Ubuntu now ships with GNU Awk v4.0+ (which provides an `inplace` module) you could do something like

```
gawk -i inplace '/eni=/ {if (++c == 2) sub(/10\*\*9/,"10**8")} 1' file
```

You can make the regular expressions `/eni=/` and/or `/10\*\*9/` more or less specific as required.

Similarly in perl

```
perl -i -pe 'if (/eni=/) {s/10\*\*9/10\*\*8/ if (++$c == 2)}' file
```

Answer (score 3):

Using [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html):

```
sed -i ': 1 ; N ; $!b1 ; s/eni\=10\.\*10\*\*9/eni\=10\.\*10\*\*8/2' filename
```

`/` is one of the [delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33914360/10785056) and `\` is the [escape character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character). `\` is used so that bash won't interpret special characters as some command, like `*` as wildcard.

Comment: This answer will match the second occurrence of `eni=10.*10**9` in a new line and will change it with `eni=10.*10**8`. Run it only once.